# Zabbix problem reporting shows "Problem name: No Instance(s) Available." on a trigger from a healthy hosts

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

After reverting to a month old DB schema (Postgres), I started getting thousands of the following problem notifications:

[image]

The host is healthy and I can't see anything relevant on the server log. 
The trigger for this problem is a python script, here is what I see on the agent log:

```
6316:20181018:024953.048 In process_active_checks() server:'zabbix.xxx.local' port:10051
6316:20181018:024953.048 Executing command 'c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"'
6316:20181018:024953.408 EXECUTE_STR() command:'c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"' len:0 cmd_result:''
6316:20181018:024953.408 for key [system.run[c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"]] received value []
6316:20181018:024953.408 In process_value() key:'xx-xx-xxxxx:system.run[c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"]' value:''
6316:20181018:024953.408 In send_buffer() host:'zabbix.xxx.local' port:10051 entries:0/100
6316:20181018:024953.408 End of send_buffer():SUCCEED
6316:20181018:024953.408 buffer: new element 0
6316:20181018:024953.408 End of process_value():SUCCEED
6316:20181018:024953.408 In need_meta_update() key:system.run[c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"]
6316:20181018:024953.408 End of need_meta_update():FAIL
```

The script works fine and had been working fine for a while. I started getting this message on multiple agents simultaneously. 
Any idea what can cause this?

Comment: This is a custom script, so it is unlikely anybody would be able to tell what exactly is happening. You also haven't provided the trigger expression. In any case, all of the entries in the screenshot show "RESOLVED", so it was likely caused by Zabbix seeing very old values at first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure I understand how the script is related to this issue. It runs perfectly manually and it had also been running for months before this issue started happening all of a sudden on multiple machines. I've looked at Zabbix manual and couldn't find what "Problem name: No Instance(s) Available." actually means.

Comment: The trigger is: {SU-b5-WV32-6:system.run[c:\Python37\python.exe "c:\x\x.py"].strlen()}>0